# How to apply formatting to text in a textarea or an alternative to textarea that allows formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, textarea

I'm making an HTML5 game and I have a chatbox going right now using the `textarea` element in HTML5. It'd be really nice if I could selectively color/bold/italicize certain lines in the chat.

I was looking around and I'm not sure if it can be done. First, can it be done natively using the latest web technologies? If not, what are some good and simple alternatives to a textarea that would work on Firefox/Opera/Safari/Chrome and offer similar functionality to the textarea?

Thanks!

Comment: First, the content of a `textarea` element can't be formatted: It's always plain text. Second, are you trying to format an input field, or are you talking about formatting the output (i.e. the "chatted" text)?

Comment: In that case, you can wrap the text in practically any kind of html element, and format it as you see fit using CSS and javascript. I'd probably have the chat be an `ol` with `li`s for the message since a chat is an ordered list of messages (semantically speaking). How _exactly_ you go about it is up to you; it's entirely open-ended.